# Strange JS function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing website. Using 2 libraries at same page: jQuery UI and Twitter Bootstrap.

I single-stepped through combobox code, and when it called .button() it went into bootstrap.min.js, not jqui.js. The question is, how to resolve the conflict between these two libraries?

BTW, Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBXRn/) where it works well without bootstrap

Comment: You didn't single-step, _I_ did. See my answer in your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537325/jquery-ui-combobox-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If button is the only conflict then you may save $.fn.bootstrap_button = $.fn.button after loading bootstrap, and then load jqueryui. Or you may configure and download bootstrap without button widget.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap button too. http://i.stack.imgur.com/UczuN.png If you can get this dropdown functionality in jquery-ui please help me to get ridd of bootstrap and use only jQ-ui

Comment: Something like this but with ready to go dropdown http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

Comment: You can have your own menu and show it when button is clicked, something like jqueryui autocomplete does but without text input field http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox